# Linked List Stops after 2 nodes, why?

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

First post here. I'm trying to implement linked list with code below but somehow the linked list would stop after 2nd node. I was expecting 9->6->11->8->15->19->7->, but I got 9->6-> only.
Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem with my code? 
Thanks!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.next = None
        self.val = value
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.val)

class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    def append_node(self,value):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.tail = Node(value)  
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(value)
            self.tail = Node(value)
        return self


llist = SLinkedList()
llist.append_node(9).append_node(6).append_node(11) \
.append_node(8).append_node(15).append_node(19) \
.append_node(7)  

print(llist.head.next.next) # returned None. Why??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work if you replace `self.tail = Node(value)` with `self.tail = self.tail.next`.  Your current version sets `self.tail.next` to a new node with the given value, and then sets `self.tail` to a *different* node with the same value.  They need to be the same node for a linked list to work properly.  `self.tail.next`  is a node that is *equivalent* to `Node(value)`, but `Node(value)` makes a new object.  You need them to both be the same object. If they aren't the same object `self.tail` will be a separate object and not part of the linked list.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tail.next = Node(value)    
self.tail = Node(value)
```

Here you are giving the same object to be in two nodes, which is not what is actually needed. you need to say, now make the `self.tail.next` the tail, ie `self.tail`

Thus change `self.tail = Node(value)` to `self.tail = self.tail.next`

```
class SLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
    def append_node(self,value):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.tail = Node(value)
        else:
            self.tail.next = Node(value)
            self.tail = self.tail.next
        return self
```

Answer (score 0):

When `self.head` is not empty, `append_node()` is creating two new nodes. It puts one in the `next` link of the old tail, then sets `self.tail` to the other one. As a result, `self.tail` is pointing to a node that isn't actually in the `next` chain. So when you later add a new node after it, that's not part of the list.

Assign the new node to a variable, and then assign that in both places.

```
    def append_node(self,value):
        new_node = Node(value)
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = self.tail = new_node
        else:
            self.tail.next = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
        return self
```

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand now. Wow I didn't expect my question to be answered so quickly, and by multiple people. This is an awesome community!